# Access an item that stored in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

If I have some code

```
itemdata = csgo_check_item(param_a, param_d, param_m)
print(itemdata)
```

that outputs

```
(iteminfo {
  itemid: 8808072743
  defindex: 24
  paintindex: 175
  rarity: 1
  quality: 4
  paintwear: 1059729780
  paintseed: 484
  inventory: 3221225482
  origin: 24
}
,)
```

How can I put paintwear into its own variable?
I tried `float1 = get_float(itemdata.paintwear)`
but that gives me

```
    float1 = get_float(itemdata.paintwear)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'paintwear'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As your `itemdata` variable is a tuple you should use index in order to access the internal data.

```
itemdata[0].paintwear
```

If you have some elements in that tuple you could run through the elements:

```
for item in itemdata:
    print (item.paintwear)
```

As juanpa suggested in comments, you can try `itemdata[0]["paintwear"]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I now get this error: `float1 = get_float(itemdata[0].paintwear)
AttributeError: 'CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_Client2GCEconPreviewDataBlockRe' object has no attribute 'paintwear'`

Comment: @AndersonP Well, then figure out how you are suppose to get `paintwear` from a `CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_Client2GCEconPreviewDataBlockRe` object... Maybe `itemdata[0]['paintwear']`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, although now I get `TypeError: 'CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_Client2GCEconPreviewDataBlockResponse' object is not subscriptable` Looking into it, this error might be easier to find

Comment: @AndersonP You need to read the documentation for the type of class that object belongs to, instead of guessing and checking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I figured out a way to get the number in a super round about way. Is there a way to figure out what type of class it is so that I can read the documentation? http://csgo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csgo.enums.html is where I know to look, but I couldn't find anything that looked like what I needed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can't figure it out, documentation has nothing on it that I can find. I have tried `itemdata[0]['paintwear']` & `iteminfo.paintwear` & `itemdata[6]` and `ithemdata.iteminfo.paintwear` and have had no luck. If you could help me I would apriciate it very much, thanks!